# grrovyTest$_run_closure1_closure3_closure4_closure5@4d1abd getting displayed under div while generating html

Tags: groovy

I get this extra value when I try to generate an html using groovy, here is my code and output below

code:

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder
println("let us try a HTML page..\n")
def mkp= new MarkupBuilder()
mkp.html{head{ title "bijoy's groovy"
    body{
        div{style:"color:red"}
            {p "this is cool"}
    }}}
```

and the output has grrovyTest$_run_closure1_closure3_closure4_closure5@4d1abd as extra.. how do I remove it?

```
 <html>
      <head>
    <title>bijoy's groovy</title>
    <body>
      <div>grrovyTest$_run_closure1_closure3_closure4_closure5@4d1abd
        <p>this is cool</p>
      </div>
    </body>
  </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attributes to a DOM element are mentioned in `()` with a map representation as shown below for `<div>`.

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder
println("let us try a HTML page..\n")

def writer = new StringWriter()
def mkp = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
mkp.html{
   head{ 
      title "bijoy's groovy"
   }
   body{
      div(style:"color:red"){
         p "this is cool"
      }
   }
}

println writer
```

Also note, I rectified `head` and `body` and added a `writer`. I suppose you do not want `body` inside html `head`. :)

Comment: Thanks @dmahapatro, () made the difference. I did not want to use a writer also..